# Discord Bot shuts down whenever a user sends it a dm

Tags: discord.js

My bot saves chat logs, it works perfectly until someone dms the bot. Here is the code that logs messages.

```
console.log(message.author.username, "||", message.channel.name, "-", message.content);
        let channel = message.channel.name;
        var readmessagefile = fs.readFileSync('./txt-files/logs.txt', 'utf-8');
        var writemessagefile = fs.writeFileSync('./txt-files/logs.txt', 'Time - ' +
        message.createdAt + ' Channel: ' + channel + " ||" + ' User - ' + message.member.user.username + ': ' +
        message.content + "\n" + readmessagefile);
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to completely ignore dms so it doesn't mess anything up.

Here is the error:

```
C:\Documents\Projects\DiscordBot\commands\logs.js:11
        message.createdAt + ' Channel: ' + channel + " ||" + ' User - ' + message.member.user.username + ': ' +
                                                                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
```

Comment: message.member is equal to null. You need to figure out why that is happening and then you will be able to fix the problem. Maybe message.user instead?

Comment: You did not initiate the `user` field (It's a Null) in object `member` that it a field in the var `message`. Can you show us more code? maybe when and after `message` is created?

Comment: @cs641311 I replaced message.member.user.username by message.author.username and it fixed my problem. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) docs:

> Represents the author of the message as a guild member. Only available if the message comes from a guild where the author is still a member

The problem is that DMs are not sent in a guild, and thus `message.member` returns `null`. You should be using [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) which also has a [`username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) property, and is available globally.

[`message.member.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) and `message.author` technically return the same thing. `message.author` is the User object of whoever authored the message. `message.member` is the GuildMember object of whoever authored the message. `GuildMember.user` is the User object of a GuildMember.

They both return the same thing, but one takes an extra step to do so.

```
Author >> User (message.author)
Author >> GuildMember >> User (message.member.user)
```

Also, you can improve your code readability using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var writemessagefile = fs.writeFileSync(
 './txt-files/logs.txt',
 `Time - ${message.createdAt} Channel: ${channel} || User - ${message.author.username}: ${message.author.content}\n${readmessagefile}`
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not initiate the user field (It's a Null) in object member that it a field in the var message